# One of the <td> in dynamically created table has to be width unassigned to force other <td> width

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, html-table

I am getting an issue which I don't know what would be the best way to explain.

I am creating a dynamic table with HTML 5. As its dyanamic so I am forming a loop for creating tr and td as per the data.

td is being created for every day of the week. User can select which day he want to see and thus according to the days selected td is being shown.

I have implemented scrolling for tbody so made both thead and tbody has 'display:block'. Therefore I have given fixed width to the header and now I have to give fixed width to columns to align them.

Now when I assign width value to td I have to leave one of the td width value nothing so that width can be enforced on rest of the td. Thus this one td unassigned has too much width. 
If I put width td in all then none of them have the width assigned by me and whole table goes out of sync.

I am putting my HTMl where I am generating td in loop at the end as header. As you can see there is no width assigned to just one td in loop. I am using bootstrap for css. Please let me know what I am doing wrong in this code. Sorry to paste all code as I dont think I can reproduce this issue in fiddle.

```
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed" >
<thead style="display:block;">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2"><div style="width:50px">@Helpers.SortableColumnHeader("Zip", actionName, BuyInfo.SortBy.Zip, new ListModel() { SortInfo = Model.RootSortInfo }, containerId, rvd, null, "Root")</div></th>
        <th rowspan="2" class="text-right"><div style=" width:80px">@Helpers.SortableColumnHeader("Households", actionName, BuyInfo.SortBy.Households, new ListModel() { SortInfo = Model.RootSortInfo }, containerId, rvd, null, "Root")</div></th>
        <th rowspan="2" class="text-right"><div style=" width:40px">@Helpers.SortableColumnHeader("Sales", actionName, BuyInfo.SortBy.Sales, new ListModel() { SortInfo = Model.RootSortInfo }, containerId, rvd, null, "Root")</div></th>
        @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Client.MpiNames[0]))
        {
            <th rowspan="2" class="text-right"><div style=" width:50px">@Helpers.SortableColumnHeader(c.Client.MpiNames[0], actionName, BuyInfo.SortBy.Mpi1, new ListModel() { SortInfo = Model.RootSortInfo }, containerId, rvd, null, "Root")</div></th>
        }
        @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Client.MpiNames[1]))
        {
            <th rowspan="2" class="text-right"><div style=" width:50px">@Helpers.SortableColumnHeader(c.Client.MpiNames[1], actionName, BuyInfo.SortBy.Mpi2, new ListModel() { SortInfo = Model.RootSortInfo }, containerId, rvd, null, "Root")</div></th>
        }
        @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Client.MpiNames[2]))
        {
            <th rowspan="2" class="text-right"><div style=" width:50px">@Helpers.SortableColumnHeader(c.Client.MpiNames[2], actionName, BuyInfo.SortBy.Mpi3, new ListModel() { SortInfo = Model.RootSortInfo }, containerId, rvd, null, "Root")</div></th>
        }
        <th rowspan="2"><div style=" width:75px">@Helpers.SortableColumnHeader("Zone", actionName, BuyInfo.SortBy.Zone, Model, containerId, rvd)</div></th>
        <th rowspan="2"><div style=" width:50px">@Helpers.SortableColumnHeader("NAPI", actionName, BuyInfo.SortBy.NapiId, Model, containerId, rvd)</div></th>
        <th rowspan="2"><div style=" width:100px">@Helpers.SortableColumnHeader("Pub", actionName, BuyInfo.SortBy.Pub, Model, containerId, rvd)</div></th>
        <th rowspan="2"><div style=" width:35px">@Helpers.SortableColumnHeader("Type", actionName, BuyInfo.SortBy.PubType, Model, containerId, rvd)</div></th>
        @for (int d = 0; d < dows.Length; d++)
        {
            <th colspan="3" class="text-center"><div style=" width:162px">@dows[d].ToDisplayString()</div></th>
        }
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @for (int d = 0; d < dows.Length; d++)
        {
            <th class="text-right"><div style=" width:42px">@Helpers.SortableColumnHeader("Zip Circ", actionName, (BuyInfo.SortBy)Enum.Parse(typeof(BuyInfo.SortBy), dows[d].ToString()), Model, containerId, rvd)</div></th>
            <th class="text-right"><div style=" width:50px">Zone Circ</div></th>
            <th class="text-center"><div style=" width:70px">Buy</div></th>
        }
    </tr>




</thead>


<tbody style="display:block;
              height: 500px;
              overflow-y: auto;
              /*width:auto;
              table-layout:fixed*/">
    @foreach (Zip zip in Model.PageList)
    {
        IComparer<Zone> comparer;
        BuyInfo.SortBy sortBy = (BuyInfo.SortBy)Model.SortInfo.SortBy;
        if (sortBy.ToString().EndsWith("day"))
        {
            DayOfWeek dow = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), sortBy.ToString());

            Dictionary<Zone, int> circs = new Dictionary<Zone, int>();
            foreach (Zone zo in b[zip].Keys)
            {
                circs.Add(zo, b[zip][zo].ContainsKey(dow) ? b[zip][zo][dow] : 0);
            }
            comparer = BuyInfo.GetZoneComparer(sortBy, Model.SortInfo.SortForward, circs);
        }
        else
        {
            comparer = BuyInfo.GetZoneComparer(sortBy, Model.SortInfo.SortForward);
        }

        int sales = Model.SalesInfo.ContainsKey(zip.Id) ? Model.SalesInfo[zip.Id].Sales : 0;

        SortedDictionary<Zone, SortedDictionary<DayOfWeek, int>> zones = new SortedDictionary<Zone, SortedDictionary<DayOfWeek, int>>(b[zip], comparer);

        if (zones.Count == 0)
        {
            <tr class="zip">
                <td><div style=" width:50px">@zip.Title</div></td>
                <td class="text-right"><div style=" width:80px">@zip.Households.ToString("n0")</div></td>
                <td class="text-right"><div style=" width:40px">@sales.ToString("c0")</div></td>
                @MpiRows(c.Client, zip, 1)
                <td colspan="@((dows.Length * 3) + 4)" class="text-center"><div style="width:@((dows.Length+4)*143)px">n/a</div></td>
            </tr>
            continue;
        }
        bool isFirstRow = true;
        foreach (Zone zone in zones.Keys)
        {
            <tr class="@(isFirstRow ? "zip" : "")"; width="500px">
                @if (isFirstRow)
                {
                    <td rowspan="@zones.Count"><div style="width:50px">@zip.Title</div></td>
                    <td rowspan="@zones.Count" class="text-right"><div style="width:80px">@zip.Households.ToString("n0")</div></td>
                    <td rowspan="@zones.Count" class="text-right"><div style="width:40px">@sales.ToString("c0")</div></td>
                    @MpiRows(c.Client, zip, zones.Count)
                    isFirstRow = false;
                }
                <td style="width:85px;" class="text-left"><div style=" width:75px; display:block">@zone.Title</div></td>
                <td style="width:60px;" class="text-left" ><div style=" width:50px; display:block">@zone.Pub.NapiId</div></td>
                <td style="width:110px;" class="text-left">
                    <div style="width:100px; display:block">
                        <span>@zone.Pub.Title</span><br />
                        <span class="text-muted">@zone.Pub.Location</span>
                        @Ajax.ActionLink("mins", "GetMinBuys", "Pub", new { id = zone.Pub.Id },
                        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "min-buy-list-container", OnFailure = "alert('Error!');", OnSuccess = "showMinBuys(this);" }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-default" })
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left" style="width:45px"><div style="width:35px; display:block">@zone.Pub.Type</div></td>
                @for (int d = 0; d < dows.Length; d++)
                {
                    DayOfWeek dow = dows[d];
                    int zipCirc = zones[zone].ContainsKey(dow) ? zones[zone][dow] : 0;
                    int zoneCirc = zone.Circ != null ? (zone.Circ.ContainsKey(dow) ? zone.Circ[dow] : 0) : 0;
                    int households = zip.Households;
                    decimal penetration = households == 0 ? Decimal.Zero : (decimal)zipCirc / households;
                    int minBuy = zone.Pub.MinBuys.ContainsKey(dow) ? zone.Pub.MinBuys[dow] : 0;
                    int buy = zone.Buy != null ? (zone.Buy.ContainsKey(dow) ? zone.Buy[dow] : 0) : 0;
                        <td class="text-right" style="width:52px;">
                            <div style="width:42px; display:block">
                                @zipCirc<br />
                                <span class="text-muted">@penetration.ToString("p0")</span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right" style="width:60px;">
                            <div style="width:50px; display:block">
                                @if (zoneCirc > 0)
                                {
                                    <a class="zone-circ" href="#">@zoneCirc</a>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @zoneCirc
                                }
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        ##<td class="text-right">##
                            <div style="width:70px; display:block">
                                @if (zoneCirc > 0)
                                {
                                    string className = String.Empty;
                                    if (buy > 0)
                                    {
                                        className = (buy >= minBuy) ? "min-met" : "min-not-met";
                                    }
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm min @(className)" placeholder="@minBuy" value="@(buy > 0 ? buy.ToString() : String.Empty)" data-campaign-id="@(c.Id)" data-zone-id="@(zone.Id)" data-dow-id="@((int)dow)" />
                                }
                            </div>
                        </td>
                }

            </tr>
        }
    }
    @if (Model.List.Count == 0)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">No pubs exist for this campaign (check the search term).</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

jsfiddle for rendered code with no width to one td:  [jsfiddle.net/9psjobhc](http://%20jsfiddle.net/9psjobhc)

Comment: Please provide the rendered code so we can assist you. It is difficult to create a functioning fix with the code you provided.

Comment: @Ted: Please look at this jsfiddle. I have not included width in one of the td in loop and hence columns are scattered everywhere. http://jsfiddle.net/9psjobhc/

Comment: Here [http://jsfiddle.net/xa3bj7sh/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/xa3bj7sh/1/)... now wheres the problem specifically?

Comment: Just remove 4 days from the headers so that we can see data for only three days. In that case as we have not assigned any width to one td so the Buy box td have some unexpected width. Now if we assign a width say '85px' to the unassigned td then none of them will have any assigned width. Code works when all days are there but doesn't when we decrease the days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for my issue. I just looped through the days and inserted blank td at the last day of the loop. Hence the space required by td is assigned at the end and sync remains as its needed.